# How to modify code for s_client?

Tags: c, linux, networking, ssl, openssl

I'm playing around with `apps/s_client.c` in the `openssl` source code. I want to make a few changes and run it, but my changes are not getting reflected after I save the file and do a `make all`, or a `make`.

For example, I changed the `sc_usage` function to this:

```
BIO_printf(bio_err,"This is how you use s_client\n");
BIO_printf(bio_err,"usage: s_client args\n");
BIO_printf(bio_err,"\n");
BIO_printf(bio_err," -host host     - use -connect instead\n");
BIO_printf(bio_err," -port port     - use -connect instead\n");
```

I then save and do a `make all` in the `apps` folder, but when I run the program by doing this: `openssl s_client abc`, I don't see the line I introduced, `this is how you use s_client`, in the output.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you run the correct app? Try `./openssl`.

In Linux, current directory is not searched for executable files by default, so you are probably running system's `openssl`.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to make a few changes and run it, but my changes are not getting reflected after I save the file and do a make all, or a make.

Its even easier than that once you know the tricks.

1. Configure the OpenSSL library as normal (`configure`)
2. Build the OpenSSL library as normal (`make depend && make`)
3. Install the OpenSSL library as normal (`sudo make install`)
4. Make your changes to `s_client.c`
5. Compile `s_client.c` in place (the `apps/` directory):

Here's the grease. You have to build some additional object files, like `apps.o` and `apps_rand.o`, to support `s_client.o`.

```
export OPENSSLDIR=/usr/local/ssl/darwin    
gcc -DOPENSSL_NO_PSK -DMONOLITH -I$OPENSSLDIR/include -I../ -c apps.c    
gcc -DOPENSSL_NO_PSK -DMONOLITH -I$OPENSSLDIR/include -I../ -c app_rand.c    
gcc -DOPENSSL_NO_PSK -DMONOLITH -I$OPENSSLDIR/include -I../ -c s_cb.c
gcc -DOPENSSL_NO_PSK -DMONOLITH -I$OPENSSLDIR/include -I../ -c s_socket.c

gcc -DOPENSSL_NO_PSK -I$OPENSSLDIR/include -I../ \
  app_rand.o apps.o s_cb.o s_socket.o \
  $OPENSSLDIR/lib/libssl.a $OPENSSLDIR/lib/libcrypto.a \
  s_client.c -o my_s_client.exe
```

The `OPENSSL_NO_PSK` is needed because a declaration (`psk_key`) was commented out. The `-I../` is needed because `e_os.h` is not installed after a `make install`. It sure would be nice if OpenSSL actually tested their stuff before releasing it...

Then:

```
$ ./my_s_client.exe -connect www.google.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=www.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 ...
```

No need to rebuild the whole library or all the apps. No need for `openssl s_client ...`.