# Running a 32-bit C code on a 64-bit system with Windows and a C compiler

Tags: c, linux, mingw

I am trying to run a c code on my Windows laptop using the 64-bit MinGW compiler. There are a few lines in the beginning of the code that direct to other files such as:

```
#include <openssl/e_os2.h>
```

When compiling the code the following error shows up:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\openssl\apps>gcc s_server.c
s_server.c:21:27: fatal error: openssl/e_os2.h: No such file or directory
#include <openssl/e_os2.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

I made sure the files were in the correct locations, however the error still occurs. I am thinking the error occurs because I am running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system. Are there any ways to work around this issue given that I don't have a Linux system?

Comment: [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). Visual Studio Community. Exactly what do you want to link openssl with?

Comment: Also see [How to modify code for s_client?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28313713/608639) It takes you through compiling a new version of `s_client.c` as a stand-alone program. You might also be interested in [How to run different 'modes' of a program based on command line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27660746/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C:\MinGW\bin\openssl\apps>gcc s_server.c
s_server.c:21:27: fatal error: openssl/e_os2.h: No such file or directory
#include <openssl/e_os2.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

I believe you need a `-I` argument during compile. The headers are *not* located in the `apps/` directory. Instead, they are located at `../include/` (relative to `apps/`).

So maybe a compile command like:

```
# from apps/ directory
gcc -I ../include/ s_server.c
```

You will probably have additional problems because you need to link against `libssl` and `libcrypto`. Be aware you will still have work to do.

---

Here is what it looks like on Linux:

```
openssl$ find . -name e_os2.h
./include/openssl/e_os2.h

openssl$ cd apps

apps$ ls ../include/openssl/e_os2.h
../include/openssl/e_os2.h
```

Since the relative path is `../include/openssl/e_os2.h` and the source file `#include "openssl/e_os2.h"`, you only need to include `../include` using `-I`.

---

> I am running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system...

You need to build OpenSSL as 32-bit. Run `./Configure LIST` to get a list of MinGW targets. Then, configure with the appropriate triplet.

You may need to add `-m32` to the command line for your program.

Comment: The e_os2.h file is located in an `include` folder outside of `apps/` but there is a folder inside `apps/` that is also called `include`. Will it work to copy and paste the e_os2.h file from one `include` folder to the other within `apps/`?