# s_client implementation code for EAP-TLS

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

Hi I am new to OpenSSL so please ignore if its not valid question.
I just want to  initiate EAP-TLS session between client and server. So, I am using below mentioned command

```
openssl s_client -connect <ip-address>:<Port-NO> -tls1
```

and Its working fine but I want same to be happen using c code.

Is there any c code implementation for s_client -connect ??

Comment: http://osxr.org/openssl/source/apps/s_client.c

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any c code implementation for s_client -connect ??

Yes, there is.

Check in `<openssl src>/apps/s_client.c`. That's the source code for the `s_client` sub command. Or, visit OpenSSL's [openssl/apps/s_client.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/s_client.c).

You can *even* build `s_client` as stand alone with symbols so you can step it/debug it in-place. See [How to run different 'modes' of a program based on command line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27660746/608639)

---

> ... EAP-TLS

As for the question on EAP-TLS... I ***don't*** think OpenSSL provides it. But I could be wrong.

I looked at the proposed standard a couple of years ago, and its more of a "framework" to plug-in authentication methods over a TLS (or into a TLS) channel. See [RFC 5216](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5216.txt) (TLS) and [RFC 6347](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6347.txt) (DTLS).

To use EAP-TLS, you need a "Keying Material Exporter". That's part of [RFC 5705](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5705.txt). I think the idea is to use your authentication method to produce the `premaster_secret` or `master_secret`, and then turn control back over to TLS.